# Переименовать столбец

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa

Не могу понять почему я не могу изменить название переменой при заносе в базу данных(подгоняю под существующую)

```
   @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String secondName;
    @Column(name = "photo_max_orig")
    private String picture;
```

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": null,
  "secondName": null,
  "picture": null
}
```

Как видите в базе все равно сохраняется "firstName" вместо "first_name"

Может тут что не так

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:root}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:****}
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

В `Hibernate 5` были произведены небольшие изменения в части стратегий наименований. Необходимо указать следующие настройки. В противном случае наименование аннотации Column будет игнорироваться.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

- [Spring Boot Issue
  2129](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2129)
- [Spring Boot Issue
  6264](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6264)
- [Spring Boot + JPA : Column name annotation ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875123/378151)

Comment: Даже удалил и создал заново базу, ничего не поменялось